# Doctrine 2.0 mini tutorial error - The 'class-dir' argument is required for this driver

Tags: php, doctrine

I am getting

> orm:schema-tool => The supplied
>   configuration uses the annotation
>   metadata driver. The 'class-dir'
>   argument is required for this driver.

When I try to follow the Doctrine 2.0 alpha (I know it's alpha) [mini tutorial](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/2_0/en/introduction#sandbox-quickstart:mini-tutorial)

I am on Windows 7 x64, wamp 2. I ran

```
php.exe doctrine.php orm:schema-tool --create
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From within the same directory:

```
php.exe doctrine orm:schema-tool --create --class-dir=./Entities
```